# Is there a more concise way of assigning properties to components in react?

Tags: reactjs

Using react, I often find myself doing stuff like:

```
render() {
  var a, b, c = ...
  return <SomeClass a={a} b={b} c={c}/>
}
```

I tried doing `<SomeClass a b c/>` but it doesn't assign the properties to the component. Is there a more concise way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try use `Object`(*you can use new `ES2015` feature called [`Object Literal Property Value Shorthand`](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand.html)* in order to avoid `{ a: a, b: b, c: c }`) and [`spread attributes`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html), like so

```
const a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
return <SomeClass {...{ a, b, c } } />
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/42825/)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `{... ext}` syntax of ES6.

For example, you can get the same result as in your example by doing:

```
render() {
  var props = { a: ..., b: ..., c: ... }
  return <SomeClass {...props}/>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [JSX spread attributes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html) with [ES6 object literal shorthand property initialization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions):

```
<SomeClass {...{a, b, c}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well those were some quick answers, but yes as everyone's mentioned, the spread attribute in ES6 is commonly used to accomplish this:

```
var props = { a: 'Jim', b: 'Bob', c: 'Bill' };
return <MyComponent {...props} />
```

It's also useful to know that the order you define your props on the component is important, and can often be used to do loose conditional work, later props will override previous ones, so you can do things like:

```
var props = { a: 'Jim', b: 'Bob', c: 'Bill' };

return <MyComponent {...props} a={"James"} /> //Override 'Jim' with 'James'
```

Or:

```
var option = { a: 'Jim', b: 'Bob', c: 'Bill' };

return <MyComponent c={"William"} d={"Henry"} {...props} />
```